# MVC3 routing to a specific controller with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

I am trying to make it possible so if someone tryes to go to /content they are sent to a specfic controller (in this case content and then the following details after in the url are passed as parameters.

the url is `http://localhost:51118/content/1/7/test.html`

i have tried:

```
routes.MapRoute("content", "content", new { controller = "Content", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

im trying to integrate a cms thats why the url is what it is

EDIT:

```
public class ContentController : Controller
{    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new Content();     
             return View(model);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is not correct. You will get routed to the Content controller only when you will access the `http://localhost:51118/content` url. If you want to specify more paramateres you should add more sections to your route. 
`routes.MapRoute("content", "content/{id1}/{id2}/{content}", new { controller = "Content", action = "Index"});`

```
public class ContentController : Controller
{    
        public ActionResult Index(int id1, int id2, string content)
        {
            var model = new Content();     
             return View(model);
        }
}
```

Comment: how do i get the id's out on my controller?